# Ideals, Prime & Maximal for Quotients and Ring of Fractions

Tags: ring-theory

I was wondering how does the ideals of $\frac{R}{I}$ and $S^{-1}R$ looks like?

ideals of $\frac{R}{A}$
If $J$ is an ideal of $R$, then $\frac{J}{I}$ is an ideal of $\frac{R}{I}$. However for well-definedness it is necessary that $I\subset J$.

Thus I conclude that any ideal $J$ of $R$ containing $I$ gives rise to an ideal $\frac{J}{I}$ of $\frac{R}{I}$.

Now conversely how do I proceed. Any reference?

What to do about ring of fractions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a ring homomorphism $T:R\to A$ and $J\subset A$ is an ideal, then $T^{-1}(J)=$ is an ideal of $R$.Now the direct image of an ideal need not to be an ideal (Consider the injection $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$ and the ideal $2\mathbb{Z}$) even if $T$ is surjective(as u mentionned $J$ need to contain $Ker(T)$).In conclusion, if  $T:R\to A $ is a surjective homomorphism,then it induces a one-to-one correspondence
between ideals of $R$ containing $Ker(T)$ and ideals of $A$ (in your setting $\pi R\to R/I$ is a surjective hommomorphism with $Ker(\pi)=I$) $$ $$ Concerning the ring of fractions, u have a canonical hommomorphism ,not surjective in general: $f:R\to S^{-1}R$, so the direct image of an ideal is not necessarly an ideal,So u need to know about [extension and contraction of ideals](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/commalg/extcon.html), one can prove that every ideal of $S^{-1}R$ is a an extension of an ideal of $R$ (more precisely, the extension of its contraction). if an ideal has a non-empty intersection with $S$,then its extesnion is all of $S^{-1}R$(since elements of $S$ are invertibles in $S^{-1}R$) and prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ correspond to prime ideals of $R$ contained in the complement of $S$.